# How to remove text when it reaches a div point using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have this code. At the minute the text when loaded gets more text added on at 200px.

```
$(function() {
  var text = $(".text");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 200) {
      text.removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      text.addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

What Jquery code do I need to completely hide all this text once a div called homeIm2 has been reached when scrolling?

```
<ul class="text hidden">
        <li>S</li>
        <li class="ghost">e</li>


        <li class="spaced">E</li>
        <li class="ghost">n</li>
        <li class="ghost">v</li>

        <li class="spaced">F</li>
        <li class="ghost">i</li>


        <li class="spaced">A</li>

    </ul>

    <div class="homeInfo1">
        {{ page.intro|richtext }}
    </div>

    <table class="overview">
        <tr>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
            <td>
               ...
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!--div for image of environment-->
                <div class="homeIm2">
                    {{ page.environmentImage|richtext }}
                </div>
            </td>
```

Currently when hidden typed in the class the text that is display is SE ENV FI A

Comment: Please include the corresponding HTML code.

Comment: show your html code , r u using bootstrap?

Comment: @DEEPAK thats the relevant HTML there is it not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$(function() {
  var text = $(".text");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 200) {
      text.show();
    } else {
   text.hide();
   }
   if(scroll > $('.homeIm2').offset().top) { // when the div with homeIm2 class scrolls into view
         //add logic here to hide necessary text
   } 
  });
});
```

and then hide using the class above

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean sorry?

Comment: yeah I have updated the answer a bit. does it help ?

Comment: Are you suggesting adding this code in the if statement `text.removeClass("text hidden");`?

Comment: what does the hidden class do ?

Comment: Hidden shows/hides text.  Code that should be inside is `text.hide();` works    Do you want to add it to your answer?

Comment: Only slight problem is the text doesnt get removed till the text is inline with the middle of the div rather than the top?

Comment: can you create a sample in jsfiddle so I can help debug the actual cause ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/joel081112/o1qv6gc2/ That should be a link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8jbvdtnq/ does this solve the problem ? I think you are using the wrong selector

Comment: Problem is the text disappears when the div gets to the top of the screen rather than when text reaches div

Comment: add the `text.hides();` to your answer and ill give it a tick :)